# Histograms using Plotly Animation for 3D Image data (Python)

Tags: python, animation, plotly, histogram

I animated my image data (180, 256, 344) using following piece of code:

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.imshow(
    img, animation_frame=0, binary_string=True, labels=dict(animation_frame="slice")
)
fig.show()
```

Now I want to show histograms for all these 180 images using the same animation. Yes I want to achieve imshow animation using frame but for histograms. I have data of 180 images in the form of numpy.ndarray as (180, 256, 344). The function I wrote above is perfectly working making an animation of images. I want to animate histograms of all images. Can someone help?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Can you add more details - Are you referring to histogram: https://plotly.com/python/histograms/ -> So may be you can "draw" a sketch / mockup what you want to achieve -> https://plotly.com/python/imshow/ depending on your goal you need an array

Comment: Yes I want to achieve imshow animation using frame but for histograms. I have data of 180 images in the form of numpy.ndarray as (180, 256, 344). The function I wrote above is perfectly working making an animation of images. I want to animate histograms of all images.